# Unity 3D : Simple model make lag on mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, blender, lag

I have checked Google or the Unity Community but no answers to my specific question.

**Description of the problem**

I am creating a simple game for Android in Low Poly Style and I want to optimize it for this platform.  All of my models are made with Blender and there working fine.

I also created a simple house, made of cube with Blender but when the player is near the house, the game lag ! So I decided to make this house with some cube in Unity 3D, to see if it is lagging:

[image]

*Blue = the player, Red AND yellow = the direction where the player looks*

And surprise, the game lag too! And really. I don't know why. As you can see, this is a very simple house. When the player is front of the door and can see the inside house (yellow arrow), the game lag but when the player rotate the camera to see other part of the environment (red arrow), no lag.

**Attempt of resolution**

- I decreased the number of vertices, faces and edges for all of my Blender models including my house but this house is already lagging.
- I decrease the side view of the camera player.
- I checked the occlusion culling but there is nothing to do.
- I recreated a new Blender file for my house but the problem is always here
- I also exported my mesh in *.obj/*.fbx but the lag is always here

**My question**

What is wrong with Blender/Unity ? What can I do ?

**EDIT**

Here is a video of my problem. As you can see, when the player see the house, it is lagging but when the house is not visible in the camera player, pfuit, no lag: [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5c6ema0EdG_NmdfQzhXaHpEanM)

**Profiler**

Here is the profile when I play the game on mobile:

[image]

*Red part -> Player see the environnement, Yellow part -> Player look at the house*. I can see in the overview screen the "Graphics.PresentAndSync" increase of 10-15% when the player sees the house. I will check that in detail.

Comment: You can select Stats in the editor above the Game window and see number of Triangles and Vertices - are there more when you look inside the house?

Comment: @ḞḹáḿíṅḡⱫỏḿƀíé Thank you for your answer. It is really weird. When I look the house I have ~6K vertices and it is lagging but when I look the other environnement (red cross), I have ~20K vertices and no lag.

Comment: Does the lag happen in Editor?

Comment: @zwcloud Thanks for your question. No. There is no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I have made the update of Unity 3D to the last version 5.5.2f1 and that solve my problem. I will check if others solutions can be found to this problem and give you a feedback asap but this update make clearly the difference.

Many thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 1):

To find the real cause of the lag, you should profile your app on Android. See **Android** part of [Profiler window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and your solutions. I added a picture of the profiler. I will also check more in detail and find what the problem is